# How to change background image of a Div using Conditionals in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the 'background image' of a div whenever the variable 'healthPotionAmount reaches zero. I want it that when that condition is met, the resultant picture is: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4QK8.jpg" and when hovered there is no noticable difference.

```js
if(healthPotionAmount == 0){
//What I'm trying to find
}
```

```css
#healthPotion {
   background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/EXiNh2M.jpg');
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
}
#healthPotion:hover {
   background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/nhZaKud.jpg');
    width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="healthPotion"></div>
```

Help appreciated,
Macint0sh_Plus

Comment: You could add `#healthPotion.zeroHealth { ... }` in your stylesheet, and then in your JS `if` add the `zeroHealth` class to the element. If you're saying in that case you also want to prevent the image changing on hover then `#healthPotion.zeroHealth, #healthPotion.zeroHealth:hover { ... }`. By the way, you shouldn't need to repeat the `width` and `height` in the `:hover` style, you only need to include properties that should be different on hover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here ya go! I put in a prompt for the `healthPotionAmount` so you can test the values.

```js
var healthPotionAmount = prompt('Enter potion amount:');

if (healthPotionAmount == 0) {
    document.getElementById('healthPotion').className += ' empty';
}
```

```css
#healthPotion {
   background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/EXiNh2M.jpg');
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
}
#healthPotion:hover {
   background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/nhZaKud.jpg');
    width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
}
#healthPotion.empty {
   background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/RvhXjej.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div id="healthPotion"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```js
var healthPotionAmount = 0;
if(healthPotionAmount == 0){
//What I'm trying to find
  document.getElementById('healthPotion').className += ' no-potion';
}
```

```css
#healthPotion {
   background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/EXiNh2M.jpg');
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
}
#healthPotion.no-potion {
   background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/nhZaKud.jpg');
}
#healthPotion:hover {
   background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/nhZaKud.jpg');
    width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="healthPotion"></div>
```

Comment: Consider adding a space before "no-potion" when adding the class, otherwise it will add onto any pre-existing classes - creating the wrong class names

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution, it uses JavaScript - so no need for jQuery or any framework here.

You can remove this temporary variable

```
var healthPotionAmount = 0;
```

from the code, that's just so you can run to test without error on StackOverflow.

```js
// Tmp variable here to avoid errors
var healthPotionAmount = 0;

if(healthPotionAmount == 0){
//What I'm trying to find
  var healthPotion = document.getElementById("healthPotion");
  healthPotion.className += " empty-potion";
}
```

```css
#healthPotion {
   background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/EXiNh2M.jpg');
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
}
#healthPotion.empty-potion {
   background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/nhZaKud.jpg');
}
#healthPotion:hover {
   background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/nhZaKud.jpg');
    width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="healthPotion"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps you out.  I am kind of imagining what you want to use this for.  This will decrement the health potion whenever you click on the potion.

```js
//define your varaibles first:
var healthPotionAmount = 3;
//Get the DOM elements and store them in variables
var hpEle = document.getElementById("healthPotion");
var numHpLeftEle = document.getElementById("potionsLeft");

//Set the number of HPs
numHpLeftEle.innerHTML = healthPotionAmount;
//Start to lose some health.
function useHealthPotion() {
  //Stop doing work when we are below 0 HPs
  if(healthPotionAmount <=0) {
    return;
  }
  //Decrement the HP count
  healthPotionAmount = healthPotionAmount-1;

  //Add the class when we are empty
  if(healthPotionAmount == 0){
    hpEle.classList.add("empty");
  }
  //Update our label.
  numHpLeftEle.innerHTML = healthPotionAmount;
}
```

```css
#healthPotion {
   background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/EXiNh2M.jpg');
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
}
#healthPotion.empty {
   background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/nhZaKud.jpg');
}
```

```html
<!--Add an onclick handler that will substract one health-->
<div id="healthPotion" onclick="useHealthPotion()"></div>x<span id="potionsLeft"></span>
```